# Dispatch within the mock store throws an error in Jest test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, axios

In my React and Redux app, trying to run my first test using Jest & TypeScript and I am unable to run the test successfully. For clarification sake, the app itself is running without errors & works well. It appears, I am setting up the Axios mock response incorrectly. When I run the Jest tests, getting following error:

> Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled
>   a constant?...

Action creator:

```
export const fetchBoats = (
  userAuthToken: string,
  filterValues: BoatSearchFilterParams = {},
  page: number = 1
) => (dispatch: any) => {
  const filterParams: string = setFilterParamsAsString(filterValues);
  const url = `${GET_BOATS}?${filterParams}&page=${page}`;
  return dispatch({
    types: [FETCH_REQUEST, FETCH_SUCCESS, FETCH_FAILURE],
    promise: axios({
      method: "get",
      url: url,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Token ${userAuthToken}`
      }
    })
  });
};
```

My test file in its current state, without assertions, is:

```
import configureStore from "redux-mock-store";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { fetchResults } from "./boats";
import axios from "axios";
const mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>;

const mockStore = configureStore([thunk]);
const store = mockStore();
jest.mock("axios");

const respObj = {
  results : ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
};

describe("Test the 'Boats' action", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    store.clearActions();
  });

  it("should have data structure matching the expected structure", () => {
    const respObj = { data: resp };
    mockedAxios.get.mockResolvedValue(respObj);
    const ac: any = store.dispatch(fetchBoats("abcabcabc"));
//    expect(ac).toContain(); commented out.
  });
});
```

How can I get the action creator to return the `respObj` response & then assert on it?

[image: jest js error]

***EDIT:***

There appears some confusion on how the action creator works. I have a custom middleware which intercepts an action with a signature as this action creator above. This action is valid & working very well :)

Comment: Does your "Action creator" actually works?

Comment: Yes, it does. Why do you ask? Disclaimer: I did rename some vars for this example to make them simpler to follow.

Comment: The code you provide is a lack of some redux middleware, maybe [redux-api-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-api-middleware) and [redux-promise-middleware](https://github.com/pburtchaell/redux-promise-middleware), please provide a **minimal completed reproducible** code. This is the key information.

Comment: @slideshowp2 I have just reinserted a comment I added previously. The app itself works well, adding the whole code for the redux middlewares & redux connection would immensely confuse the reader. The issue is how to get Jest to successfully spy on ajax requests & intercept them & return my boilerplate response as above.